# New install times out Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server

Tags: boot, 16.04, system-installation

In a new install, when the system boots post install, this is as far as it gets. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting an older kernel? Hold shift while booting and select an older version. You can also try recovery mode from the same screen.

Comment: Don't have any older versions installed. This is a brand new install, clean partitions & everything.

Comment: @ETC777 then why did you accept the answer?

Comment: I'm new & still figuring this out. Excuse me.